# What's the difference between "Term Store" and "Managed Metadata Service"?

Tags: term-store, managed-metadata-service

Are these two terms interchangeable, or is one a subset of the other?

Answer (score 1):

Managed Metadata service is a service offered by sharepoint . The MMS is divided further in taxanomies(term store),folksonomies(keywords),syndicated content types .

The managed metadata service application has two purposes, 1. To make it possible to use managed metadata and 2. Share content types. The MMS has 1 term store metadata service applications and cant share the term stores. The term store is subset of MMS .

Comment: PS : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424402(v=office.15).aspx